# Can't seem to change the default date on `date_select` in Haml with Formstastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frontend, haml

I have this `date_select` in HAML using [Formtastic](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic):

```
= f.input :starts_at, as: :date_select, selected: date, include_blank: false, order: [:day, :month, :year]
```

Date is simply a date that I parse coming in to my view:
`date = Date.parse(params[:date])`

I saw on Formtastic docs that there is a `:default` and a `:selected` variable, but whenever I set those to my date, it doesn't change the date, it is always the current date. If anybody has any idea of what I could do it'd be really appreciated!

Comment: Is the expected behavior to be able to set the default date when creating a `new` record? or when `updating` a record, having the `edit` form show the current value of the record?

Comment: I realised I didn't have a real issue when digging more I found out that I was just not looking at the right controller which was setting the date value that I was feeding to my date_select...

Answer (score 1):

It was a stupid mistake of me, I wasn't looking at the right controller at first and when I got into the right one, I found out that my `new` method was setting the date that I was feeding to my `date_select`...